# What does slug mean here?

Tags: php, wordpress, slug

```
function your_function_name() {
    wp_enqueue_style('my-script-slug',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/your_style.css');
}
```

I saw that on the forum but what is "my-script-slug", what should i write here ? I don't understand...

Thanks !

Comment: *“Name of the stylesheet. Should be unique”*: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script slug is a name you can pick yourself. It is used to refer to the script in other situations, for instance when declaring a dependency.

Comment: That's great :) The best way to communicate that is to accept my answer